# How does the word "now " to board affect this counting problem?

Tags: combinatorics

A theater has 5 rows of chairs with 6 chairs in each row. 9 theatre-goers have already entered and are seated randomly in the theatre. It is now  Peter and
Mary's turn to enter the theatre. In how many ways can they sit next to each other?

my solution is there are 6! arrangments in each row and 2! to sit Peter and Mary. The total number to seat them is there for 6!2!5 ways.

Is this argument correct or there is a need to include the 9 seated goers?
(30!-9!)2! 5

Comment: Sorry for missing "board" and use of "now", give it to mean "entered theatre already. Great discussion, that the 9-seated one affects the solution we get!

Comment: This could be the best solution  (30 - 9)! 2! 5  right?  5 takes care of the number of rows.

Comment: The answer does depend on where the nine people are seated.  For instance, if every other seat in a row is already occupied, Peter and Mary cannot sit in that row.  Even if all the seats were unoccupied, your attempt would be incorrect.  If all the seats were unoccupied, there are five ways to pick the row in which Peter and Mary sit, five ways to select a pair of adjacent seats in that row (since the pair of adjacent seats must begin in one of the first five positions), and $2!$ ways to arrange Peter and Mary in the selected seats.

Comment: Thank you @Taussig. I see that word "randomly" seated is not enough for a straight forward answer.

Comment: When you say there are 6! arrangments in each row, it is wrong.  In a row, if this row is empty, they can choose (1,2),(2,3) ... or (5,6). So only 5 places. Then multiply by 5 because 5 rows, and multiply by 2, because Peter can be before or after Mary. Total is 50, not 7200. After that, we need to consider the 9 first people, and it is another challenge.

Comment: Great Lourran, 6! assumed an incorrect assumption! Suppose the question asked about the probability that the couple sits together, would the question be ruled lacking some information on where the 9 sit? Just wondered.